# How to add top link in via custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, toplinks

How to Add top link after "My Wishlist". The link should be visible on activating my custom module.I'm using Magento 1.9. I added the following

```
   <reference name="top.links"> 
      <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="mymodule"> 
           <label>My Link</label> 
           <url helper="mymodule/quote/history/"/> 
           <title>My Link</title> 
           <prepare>true<prepare/> 
           <position>2</position> 
       </action> 
   </reference>
```

Comment: Where did you add this code?

Comment: @JaiminSutariya app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/mymodule/mymodule.xml

Comment: Make sure you added your code under `<default>` tag, because your code is correct and it should work. Also make sure your layout xml files is being called.

Comment: yes @JaiminSutariya my code has `<default>` tag. Is there any other requirement other than clearing cache

Comment: No, there is no other requirements, it will be better if you can add your `config.xml` and helper `mymodule/quote/history` code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by (This is my complete module's layout file):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
     <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                <label>Custom Home Link</label>
                <url>home</url>
                <title>Custom Home Link</title>
                <prepare/>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>10</position>
            </action>
        </reference>
        </default>    
</layout>
```

Comment: I tried all these codes.. Still the links is not appearing in the front end.. :(

Comment: @DEEPESHKUMARR Please clear your cache and make sure your layout file is being called this is tested code.

Comment: @DEEPESHKUMARR let me know if this worked

Comment: No it's not working. I cleared cache as well

Comment: I added the same code in customer.xml file under theme modern. Then the link appeared.. Is it the proper way?

Comment: Add this code in  local.xml and then check.

Comment: You mean app/etc/local.xml? The newly added link will redirect to a page in my custom module

Comment: @DEEPESHKUMARR follow this link http://inchoo.net/magento/using-local-xml-for-overriding-or-updating-xml-structure/

Answer (score 1):

Please add this local.xml or any other module xml over fronted layout folder.

```
 <default>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

Also you can follow below links for the same.

URL : http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-add-top-links-in-magento/

Comment: I already followed that link. And also already added the code u mentioned.. But no success. Is there any other requirement other than clearing cache?

Comment: yes You have to clear cache after layout update if cache is enable.

Comment: Please check below link http://www.classyllama.com/blog/editing-magentos-top-links-the-better-way